# Deleting items within Listbox that contains Group Headers

Tags: ios, delphi, listbox, ios7, delphi-xe5

I am using Delphi XE5, working on an iOS application. I have come across an access violation that occurs during my application when deleting all items from a Listbox using for example:

```
ListBox1.beginUpdate;
ListBox1.items.clear;
// do work, to re-add new data to list box
...
Listbox1.endUpdate;
```

Normally, the code above works fine and no errors occur, in fact, all the items currently get deleted from that list box. EXCEPT - I get an access violation. The only difference with this TListBox in particular compared to others, is that it has TListboxGroupHeaderItems.

My work-around has been the following solution:

```
ListBox1.BeginUpdate;
p := Listbox1.Items.Count;
while p <> 0 do begin
  ListBox1.Items.Delete(p-1)
  p := p - 1;
end;
// Do Work, re-add new data, etc.
....
ListBox1.endUpdate;
```

Anyone know of a proper way to clear all items, including groupHeaders from a TListbox without triggering an access violation ? Or is it something else wrong that I am doing ?
When ran in the debugger, it does break on `ListBox1.items.clear;`

Update (10/14/2013 2:14PM): 
No Error message when working in iOS 6 Device/Simulator, but error does occur when working with iOS7

Comment: This sounds like a bug. Submit a QC report. Incidentally your while loop is pretty funky. All you need is: `while ListBox.Items.Count<>0 do ListBox.Items.Delete(0);`

Comment: I know it is funky. lol... I had something almost exactly similar to what you have just suggested, but for some reason it was only counting either a) just the first group header and only deleting that, or b) just recognizing only the group headers as items and only deleting those, leaving the TListboxItems.

Comment: Some flaw with the implementation of the ARC model in NextGen compiler perhaps.

Comment: I guess I should have added that the error did not occur when running iOS6 but did in iOS7.

Comment: Er, I guess you should!! Submit QC report

Answer (score 0):

I've had a simular problem. My solution was the following:

```
for I := Listbox1.Count -1 downto 0 do
begin
  Listbox1.RemoveObject(Listbox1.ListItems[i]);
end;
```